# How can I fix a large gap between wall and countertop caused by bowed walls?

Tags: plaster, countertops

We live in an old house with plaster walls. We recently installed a new counter top and discovered that our walls are bowed and curvy.  There is approximately a 3/4 inch gap on either side of the bow. What is the best way to shave the counter top to fit more snugly to the wall? It's too large of a gap to caulk, and a tile back splash wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: What's the counter top made of?

Answer (score 2):

Scribe it. Use a compass (or a stick with a pencil attached to it) set to the widest gap - run the compass or stick-with-pencil along the wall, marking the countertop a set distance out from the wall. Cut along the line - if done carefully, the wavy edge of the countertop should now fit the wavy wall precisely.